# How to use nested groups of radio buttons with Antd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

It looks like [antd](https://ant.design/components) does not support nested radio button groups, so I will have to structure the input elements myself. However, if I use the [`Radio.Button`](https://ant.design/components/radio/#RadioGroup) by itself it doesn't render correctly.

Is there a way to use `Radio.Button` as a standalone component in a structure other than Radio.Group?

--- edit ---

So it is possible to use the Radio.Group directly and nest it. I have a start with the code below, so I'll post it here to for illustration.

```
import React from "react";
import { Radio } from "antd";

export class TestForm extends React.Component {
  public state = {
    level1: null,
    level2: null
  };

  private handleChange = (level: "level1" | "level2", value: any) => {
    console.log("handleChange", level, value);
    this.setState(state => ({ ...state, [level]: value }));
  };

  return (
      <Radio.Group
        onChange={evt => this.handleChange("level1", evt.target.value)}
        value={this.state.level1}
      >
        <Radio style={radioStyle} value={"a"}>
          Option A
        </Radio>
        <Radio style={radioStyle} value={"b"}>
          Option B
        </Radio>
        <Radio style={radioStyle} value={"c"}>
          Option C
        </Radio>
        {this.state.level1 === "c" ? (
          <Radio.Group
            onChange={evt => this.handleChange("level2", evt.target.value)}
            value={this.state.level2}
            defaultValue="c1"
          >
            <Radio style={radioStyle} value={"c1"}>
              Option C1
            </Radio>
            <Radio style={radioStyle} value={"c2"}>
              Option C2
            </Radio>

            <Radio style={radioStyle} value={"c3"}>
              Option C3
            </Radio>
          </Radio.Group>
        ) : null}

        <Radio style={radioStyle} value={"d"}>
          Option D
        </Radio>
      </Radio.Group>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What does it mean to use "Radio.Button" as a standalone component, how do you expect the component to look like? Example, please.

Comment: In other UI component libs like Grommet for example, you can have just a styled radiobutton and use it in whatever structure. The antd `radio.button` seems to be tied to the `radio.goup`, because if you render it by itself it looses its appearance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Radio.Group` and `Radio.Button` is just an implementation of `Button.Group`, `Button`

By saying *"Radio.Button as a standalone component"* I assume you want to use it as a single grouped radio button.

In this case, is just a `Button` component, refer to [Button, Button.Group](https://ant.design/components/button/).

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <FlexBox>
      <Radio.Group>
        <Radio.Button value="a">Hangzhou</Radio.Button>
      </Radio.Group>
      <Button>Hangzhou</Button>
    </FlexBox>
  );
}
```

[image]

[image: Edit Q-56885195-ButtonGroup]

Comment: I want to nest groups of radio buttons. So for example a group of 4 and when radio 3 is selected another subgroup appears with other options (radiobuttons or checkboxes).

I don't see the point in having a group of 1. I would use a checkbox for that.

Comment: Both the question and the description talk about "nested groups". What part should be updated?

Comment: Add an example, because you can make "nested groups" with antd, what exactly the behavior you expect...  You mentioned, "like Grommet"... adding an image will help...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the point of your example where you use Radio.Group with children directly as opposed to setting options on it. This will work for me. I was looking at the examples of the small round buttons, and missed how it is done in the vertical group example. Thanks for your help. I will post my solution with the question in a minute to clarify things.